# Play protect blocks my app on some other devices

Tags: android

I recently made an APK and tried to publish in a store "bazaar" (if you haven't heard of it, it's a store for Iran).  They say my app get blocked by play protect and I have to solve this before publishing, but there's a problem. Installed this apk on 4 devices, xiaomi note 11 pro, Samsung s21, redmi note 8 pro, pocox3, the app runs perfect and I don't get any error, so I can't see the blocked by play protect error and when you don't see the error you can't solve it. Can any one tell me how to get the error so can solve it?

I tried to sign the APK with a new key but no luck they still say it blocked by play protect.